# How do I restrict all of a PDF's editability EXCEPT for extracting and moving around pages?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, copy-protection

I am starting to sell digital PDFs, and I want my customers to be able to move pages around between PDF files they have and customize them, but I don't want anyone trying to edit individual elements like fonts and graphics.

For some reason on illustrator's PDF export, there is an option that says allow everything BUT extracting pages (the exact opposite of what I want).

Is there a way to "lock" PDF content without locking the ability to move pages?

Comment: You've got to admit, your need is considerably rare. Most wouldn't want anyone moving/extracting pages at all - even if editing content were allowed. I don't think it's possible to secure editing, but allow page extraction. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Scott Sure, it is rare, but I'm confused as to why everything BUT extracting would be a need. An easy way to high-quality rasterize that would work too.

Comment: I can't even begin to contemplate why Adobe makes certain decision with respect to functionality at times. It'll cause my head to implode.

Comment: The trouble with PDF security of any sort is that it is only imposed by the functionality of the app used to open it. Though Adobe apps all honour file protection, many others don't. You just need to find the app that ignores the particular security aspect you want to bypass. This is not 'illegal' or even 'hacking' it's just a different subset of the protection routines - none of which are actually 'compulsory'. 'Locking' PDFs is a fairly pointless exercise once you know which apps can unlock them.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well.. it's kind of like disabling right-click on a web site... sure it can be circumvented rather easily, but 98% of the time a user isn't going to go to the trouble. So I wouldn't say PDF protection is "pointless".... but you're right, its not an "insurmountable hurdle"

Comment: You can't always stop people from doing wrong things, but you can make laws to punish them if they do. I guess perhaps in your case, copyright could protect your work? Quite impossible to protect stuff you send out in the world really. Physical or digital.